Kotlin android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f07006e
Issue occured when right after attempting to "register", the kotlin app would crash,Suspect that it can't find or read the image on the drawable folder. I tried to rename the images but the issue would still persist and there seems to show no error on the android studio despite the error showing on logcat. Any help would be appreciated :)
MainActivity.kt
package com.example.lightning

import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.activity.ComponentActivity
import androidx.activity.compose.setContent
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.fillMaxSize
import androidx.compose.material3.MaterialTheme
import androidx.compose.material3.Surface
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.navigation.compose.NavHost
import androidx.navigation.compose.composable
import androidx.navigation.compose.rememberNavController
import com.example.lightning.data.Location
import com.example.lightning.data.Profile
import com.example.lightning.ui.theme.LightningTheme
import com.example.lightning.ui2.ProfileCard
import com.example.lightning.ui2.login.EmailLoginScreen
import com.example.lightning.ui2.login.LoginScreen
import androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.LazyColumn
import com.example.lightning.ui2.login.RegistrationScreen

class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            LightningTheme {
                val navController = rememberNavController()
                NavHost(navController = navController, startDestination = "login_screen") {
                    composable("login_screen") { LoginScreen(navController) }
                    composable("email_login_screen") { EmailLoginScreen(navController) }
                    composable("profile_screen") { ProfileScreen(getDummyProfileData()) }
                    composable("registration_screen") { RegistrationScreen(navController) }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // Function to get sample profile data (replace with your data source)
    private fun getDummyProfileData(): List<Profile> {
        return listOf(
            Profile(
                id = "1",
                name = "Alice Johnson",
                age = 28,
                imageUrl = "https://via.placeholder.com/150", // Placeholder image URL
                bio = "Loves hiking, traveling, and trying new foods.",
                gender = "Female",
                interests = listOf("Hiking", "Traveling", "Cooking"),
                location = Location("San Francisco", "California", "USA"),
                occupation = "Software Engineer",
                education = "Master's Degree",
                relationshipStatus = "Single",
                lookingFor = "Serious relationship"
            ),
            Profile(
                id = "2",
                name = "Bob Smith",
                age = 32,
                imageUrl = "https://via.placeholder.com/150",
                bio = "Enjoys playing guitar, watching movies, and exploring new places.",
                gender = "Male",
                interests = listOf("Music", "Movies", "Travel"),
                location = Location("New York", "New York", "USA"),
                occupation = "Musician",
                education = "Bachelor's Degree",
                relationshipStatus = "Single",
                lookingFor = "Casual dating"
            ),
            // Add more dummy profiles here...
        )
    }

    @Composable
    fun ProfileScreen(profiles: List<Profile>) {
        LightningTheme {
            Surface(
                modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background
            ) {
                LazyColumn {
                    items(profiles.size) { index ->
                        ProfileCard(profiles[index])
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}



ProfileCard.kt
package com.example.lightning.ui2 // Adjust if your package is different

import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.*
import androidx.compose.foundation.shape.CircleShape
import androidx.compose.material3.*
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.ui.Alignment
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.draw.clip
import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color
import androidx.compose.ui.layout.ContentScale
import androidx.compose.ui.res.painterResource
import androidx.compose.ui.text.font.FontWeight
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.dp
import coil.compose.AsyncImage
import com.example.lightning.R
import com.example.lightning.data.Profile

@Composable
fun ProfileCard(profile: Profile) {
    Card(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .padding(16.dp),
        elevation = CardDefaults.cardElevation(defaultElevation = 8.dp),
        colors = CardDefaults.cardColors(Color(0xFF000000)),
    ) {
        Row(
            modifier = Modifier
                .padding(16.dp)
                .fillMaxWidth(),
            verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically
        ) {
            //Profile Image
            AsyncImage(
                model = profile.imageUrl,
                contentDescription = "Profile Image",
                placeholder = painterResource(id = R.drawable.error_image),
                error = painterResource(id = R.drawable.placeholder_image),
                modifier = Modifier
                    .size(80.dp)
                    .clip(CircleShape),
                contentScale = ContentScale.Crop
            )

            Spacer(modifier = Modifier.width(16.dp))

            Column {
                Text(text = profile.name, style = MaterialTheme.typography.headlineSmall, fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold, color = Color.White)
                Text(text = "${profile.age}", style = MaterialTheme.typography.bodyMedium, color = Color.White)
                // Add more Text composables for other profile details
            }
        }
    }
}


Logcat Log
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.lightning, PID: 8673
android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f07006e
    at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.getValue(ResourcesImpl.java:240)
    at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:1511)
    at androidx.compose.ui.res.PainterResources_androidKt.painterResource(PainterResources.android.kt:61)
    at com.example.lightning.ui2.ProfileCardKt$ProfileCard$1.invoke(ProfileCard.kt:39)
    at com.example.lightning.ui2.ProfileCardKt$ProfileCard$1.invoke(ProfileCard.kt:27)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:118)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:35)
    at androidx.compose.material3.CardKt$Card$1.invoke(Card.kt:886)
    at androidx.compose.material3.CardKt$Card$1.invoke(Card.kt:93)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:109)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:35)
    at androidx.compose.material3.SurfaceKt$Surface$1.invoke(Surface.kt:134)
    at androidx.compose.material3.SurfaceKt$Surface$1.invoke(Surface.kt:115)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:109)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:35)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionLocalKt.CompositionLocalProvider(CompositionLocal.kt:228)
    at androidx.compose.material3.SurfaceKt.Surface-T9BRK9s(Surface.kt:112)
    at androidx.compose.material3.CardKt.Card(Card.kt:85)
    at com.example.lightning.ui2.ProfileCardKt.ProfileCard(ProfileCard.kt:21)
    at com.example.lightning.MainActivity$ProfileScreen$1$1$1$1.invoke(MainActivity.kt:83)
    at com.example.lightning.MainActivity$ProfileScreen$1$1$1$1.invoke(MainActivity.kt:82)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:139)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:35)
    at androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.LazyListItemProviderImpl$Item$1.invoke(LazyListItemProvider.kt:79)
    at androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.LazyListItemProviderImpl$Item$1.invoke(LazyListItemProvider.kt:77)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:109)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:35)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionLocalKt.CompositionLocalProvider(CompositionLocal.kt:248)
    at androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.layout.LazyLayoutPinnableItemKt.LazyLayoutPinnableItem(LazyLayoutPinnableItem.kt:58)
    at androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.LazyListItemProviderImpl.Item(LazyListItemProvider.kt:77)
    at androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.layout.LazyLayoutItemContentFactoryKt$SkippableItem$1.invoke(LazyLayoutItemContentFactory.kt:135)
    at androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.layout.LazyLayoutItemContentFactoryKt$SkippableItem$1.invoke(LazyLayoutItemContentFactory.kt:134)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:109)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:35)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionLocalKt.CompositionLocalProvider(CompositionLocal.kt:248)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.saveable.SaveableStateHolderImpl.SaveableStateProvider(SaveableStateHolder.kt:84)
    at androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.layout.LazySaveableStateHolder.SaveableStateProvider(LazySaveableStateHolder.kt:85)
    at androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.layout.LazyLayoutItemContentFactoryKt.SkippableItem-JVlU9Rs(LazyLayoutItemContentFactory.kt:134)
    at androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.layout.LazyLayoutItemContentFactoryKt.access$SkippableItem-JVlU9Rs(LazyLayoutItemContentFactory.kt:1)
    at androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.layout.LazyLayoutItemContentFactory$CachedItemContent$createContentLambda$1.invoke(LazyLayoutItemContentFactory.kt:101)


Steps Taken -

Clean and rebuilding of build
tried to do file -> Invalidate Caches / Restart and then restart Android Studio.
adding val resourceId = resources.getIdentifier("my_resource_name", "id", packageName) to MainActivity.kt and rebuild but issue still persists.


Is there a reason why you put a placeholder image on error and an error image for a placeholder? placeholder = painterResource(id = R.drawable.error_image),                 error = painterResource(id = R.drawable.placeholder_image),?

@tomerpacific it still should work, even if it's confusing, try maybe syncing the project with gradle files?

@JustSightseeing, Thanks for your suggestion :), I haven't tried that yet, but I'll try that once I'm back in the office..

@JustSightseeing - Didn't say it shouldn't work, was just wondering why.

managed to solved my own query. Found out that one of the affected image was stored in a different drawable folder. Upon moving to the correct folder, the error was fixed. See below for the relevant image. Thanks for all the suggestion :)
[Initial Image location][1]
[1]: https://i.sstatic.net/Vjijg3th.png
[Updated Image location][2]
[2]: https://i.sstatic.net/51SJMLLH.png
